# How to produce an if statement to compare rows in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I need to compare two rows next to each other in a column in a dataframe, if the data in both those rows matches, then save the most recent row, e.g.

```
# Animals
# 1  dog  

# 2  cat  

# 3  cat
```

It should compare dog and cat, then not save any data. So it won't save row 1 and 2.

But when it moves onto compare cat and cat, realise they are the same and save those rows. So save rows 2 and 3. As they are the same. There are several other columns but the animals column is the only one I need to use to decide whether the row is saved. However I want to keep all the data in the columns within the saved rows.
I need to do this for lots of rows, iterating through to compare a big set of data (~68,000)

I've tried to produce an if statement in which:

```
# results <- list()
# 
#  if(isTRUE(data$Animals[i+1] == data$Animals[i])) {
#   output <- print(data$Animals[i+1])
#   results[[i+1]] <- output
#   output <- print(data$Animals[i])
#   results[[i]] <- output
#  }
#}
```

I then converted this results list into a dataframe for further manipulation. However this method only provides me with the animal name, I would prefer it the entire row was saved. I'm not too sure how to achieve this, I've been trying to edit the statement but I can't seem to get it working.

I'm new to R and learning, please help anyway you can, I'd appreciate it :)

Comment: Please consider editing your query so as to make it clear. Format the table properly, so that we can understand where you're stuck. Better read the [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 1):

To "prove" that we're saving the *"most recent row"*, I'll add a row-number column. The data:

```r
dat <- structure(list(Animals = c("dog", "cat", "cat"), row = 1:3), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
dat
#   Animals row
# 1     dog   1
# 2     cat   2
# 3     cat   3
```

### base R

```r
dat[c(with(dat, Animals[-nrow(dat)] != Animals[-1])),,drop=FALSE]
#   Animals row
# 1     dog   1
# 3     cat   3
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  filter(Animals != lead(Animals, default = ''))
#   Animals row
# 1     dog   1
# 2     cat   3
```

The only caution I have with this is that if package-loading is at all out-of-order, there exists both `stats::filter` and `stats::lag` that behave completely differently. If you see odd results, try prepending `dplyr::` to make sure it isn't a which-function-am-I-using problem.

```r
dat %>%
  dplyr::filter(Animals != dplyr::lead(Animals, default = ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `lead` and `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(helper = lead(animals)) %>% 
    filter(animals == helper) %>%
    select(animals)
```

Output:

```
  animals
  <chr>  
1 cat
```

Comment: I think *"save the most recent row"* suggests that one `"dog"` should be preserved.